# What is the approach to showing the differentiability of $F(s,f) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x+s)g'(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

> Let $E$ be the set of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that are $\mathcal{C}^1$ and such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x+1)=f(x)$. Let $g \in E$ and $F: \mathbb{R} \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$F(s,f)= \int^{1}_{0}f(x+s)g'(x)dx $$
>   Show that $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Now, I found this exercise in past terms exams, so it might be possible that in order to solve it I require some notions that I haven't seen yet in my course. Anyway, I wonder, how should I approach this exercise? Is there a way to apply the Leibniz integral rule?

Comment: Looks like you need some notion of differentiability on infinite-dimensional spaces. There Gateaux respectively Frechet differentiability is probably what you are looking for. Here is a wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Fréchet differentiability, is true that continuous partial derivatives $\implies$ differentiability even in the infinite-dimensional case. Also, fixing a norm in $E$ is required, but the reasonable norm for $E$ is
$$\|f\| = \|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty.$$
($\|\cdot\|_\infty$ = $\sup$ norm)

As for $s$ fixed $f\longmapsto F(s,f)$ is obviously linear, proving continuity is enough. Taking $h\in E$:
$$
|F(s,f + h) - F(s,h)| =
\left|\int^{1}_{0}(f + h)(x + s)g'(x)\,dx - \int^{1}_{0}f(x + s)g'(x)\,dx\right| =
$$
$$
\left|\int^{1}_{0}h(x + s)g'(x)\,dx\right|\le\|g'\|_\infty\|h\|_\infty(1 - 0)
\le\|g'\|_\infty\|h\|.
$$
For the other partial derivative (the derivative of $s\longmapsto F(s,f)$), use Leibniz's rule.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact that continuity of the partial derivatives still implies differentiability even in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist, Henri Cartan, *Calcul différentiel*.